# How can I stop Microsoft from sending me unwanted data?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-firewall, glasswire

Im on a metered connection which is fairly slow during the day (faster at night) and my limit is 50GB/month. I recently did a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro and Im constantly getting data sent from Microsoft which renders my daytime connection unusable. So far I have done the following to mitigate the problem:

- Disabled Windows Telemetry
- Gone into windows privacy settings and disabled absolutely everything
- After installing the initial service packs, completely shut off windows updates
- Using windows firewall, block the IPs (see below) which are sending unwanted data to my PC

Here are the IPs I have blocked so far:

```
13.107.4.50 (c-0001.c-msedge.net biggest offender)
72.21.81.240
8.253.231.254
8.252.6.254
8.252.68.254
8.252.6.126
8.252.36.254
8.253.133.91
8.252.43.254
8.250.213.254
8.253.151.248
8.253.151.120
8.249.31.254
8.252.36.126
8.253.133.112
8.253.151.249
8.252.96.254
8.252.27.254
8.252.43.126
8.249.1.254
8.252.68.126
```

Searching around I've seen people mention that these IPs are from windows update however Ive shut windows update off and for the moment I am not concerned what negative impact that may have, I just want Microsoft to stop flooding my connection so my PC/internet is usable.

Note that all these IPs are sending data between 30 and 500K/sec even when my computer is idle no apps open or anything else running.

Any idea why all these IPs are forcing this data on me and what else I can do to mitigate the problem?

Comment: Have you marked your connection as metered?

Comment: Im using my cell phone with tethering and was unable to find that option, I did search for it but havent found one yet or it doesnt exist for my use case.